# How do I parse a .eml file using C/C++?

Tags: objective-c, parsing, eml

How do I parse .eml files using C/C++ (or preferably Objective-C)?

I looked around but couldn't find any details about the structure of the file.

Answer (score 1):

EML files are plain ASCII (7-bit) files.  The file format is specified in [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html).  The mail header will be separated from the body by an empty line.

If you will be dealing with emails that contain attachments, or characters whose value is greater than 127, you will need a base64 decoder.  maybe [this link](http://filext.com/faq/decode_eml_files.php) will help.